# Filter by Email in prisma GraphQL

Tags: graphql, prisma, graphql-playground

I'm trying to filter a user by email, I am using prisma and doing tests with the "playground", is there any way to filter the user's data by email?

My schema:

```
interface Model {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
}

type User implements Model {
  id: ID! @id
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt
  username: String
  name: String!
  surname: String!
  email: String!
  token_usuario: String! @unique
}
```

My attempts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: if `email` then why `token_usuario` ? playground hints possible fields/syntax

Comment: Ups, the screenshot is from another test, but is the same error

Comment: check server/api specs - if it (filtering) and how is supported

Answer (score 1):

Using prisma 2.0, the db client exposes something like this:

```
ctx.prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    email: { contains: "something" }
  }
});
```

And I expect the query would follow suit. So try passing in the `where` field for filtering. Would need to see the full schema to say for sure.